# Understanding iMask Settings and Notation

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins, mask

I'm planning on using [this](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/imask/#selflink_usage) plugin in my form. But I just want an better explanation of the options than what they gave you.

type: What is this? What is the fixed or number option do?
mask: does anyone have any good resources where I can learn mask notation?
stripmask: what does this mean? If it means remove mask, then why not just remove class="iMask" from the tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gleaned from the [iMask Documentation](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/imask/#selflink_usage) and some tinkering:

**Type** - Limits characters that can be entered into an input field

- Number: Defaults to a decimal value (any length). Valid characters: 0123456789
- Fixed: Limited to the characters specified in the **mask** option. No more, no less.

[**Mask**](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/imask/#selflink_features) - Dictates the format an input field value must follow

- 9: Stands for any numerical symbol. Default valid characters: 0123456789
- A: Stands for any alphabetical character. Default valid characters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
- X: Stands for any numerical OR alphabetical character

**StripMask** - Removes or preserves the mask syntax hint on an input field

- True: Removes the mask from the input field when the user is done editing. Example: `09/24/12` would become `092412` when the input field loses focus.
- False: Mask remains in input field.